# Avoiding duplicate rows in an EXCEL Pivot Table

Tags: excel

I am running EXCEL 2007 and try to do a Pivot table.

The data are the following ones:
[image]

And the table pivot result:
[image]

As you can see, I have some duplicate lines in the pivot table that I don't want.

What can be the issue? Column B are all numbers. And column C all texts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is likely to be some of your labels "Pro1" may have white space at the end. i.e. "Pro1" and "Pro1 " would be interpreted as different labels.

You can get rid by using a trim function `TRIM()` applied to your row labels.

To do so, in another column put the formula `TRIM(C2)`, and copy down until the bottom of your Pro column is reached. Then copy and **paste by value** this data **over** your Pro column. This will replace the entries "Pro1 " (with space at end) with "Pro1" (no space at end). You can then get rid of the extra column you created.

Once this is done, to reflect the changes, the pivot table will need to be refreshed.

There are other ways to do this, but this is the most direct and straight forward.

Comment: Rusan, unfortunately this is not the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Could you share your excel file?

Comment: Did you apply formula to all your data, or just eye-ball? Pivot tables aggregate similar data. They do not contain duplicate rows. Therefore there *must* be a difference between different "Pro1" somewhere. Notice that it looks like **only 1** "Pro1 " (with space, or a difference) entry exists. In fact it is **row 6**.

Comment: Rusan, you were right. This solve the issue. I just have had to make it on several columns. Thanks.